# I need help to evaluate this definite integral.

Tags: integration

I need help to evaluate this definite integral:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^x)\sin x}dx$$

http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP10132037a3e08cdcibh400001i6fai6eh0c6053c?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=19&w=140.&h=39.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^x)\sin x}dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^x)\sin x}dx + \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^x)\sin x}dx$$

Make the substitution $x \to -x$ in the second integral, then it becomes:

$$I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^x)\sin x}dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{(1+2^{-x})\sin x}dx =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}dx$$

For $n \ge 2$,

$$I_n - I_{n-2} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin nx - \sin (n-2)x}{\sin x}\,dx = 2\int_0^{\pi} \cos (n-1)x\,dx = 0$$

Hence, $I_n = 0$ if $n$ is even and $\pi$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @AlexSilva It cancels after you make the substituion in the second integral and add it to the first.

Comment: @AlexSilva yes $\frac{1}{1+2^x} + \frac{1}{1+2^{-x}} = \frac{1}{1+2^x} + \frac{2^x}{1+2^x} = \frac{1+2^x}{1+2^x} = 1$

Comment: I see  it! Thanks!:)

Comment: thank!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DaniloColazzo welcome:)